# PRISM 4.0 project gives build error

Tags: prism-4

i have created a new silverlight project using PRISM and i have included microsoft.practices.prism.dll but in the module class it gives the error:the type or namespace "practices" does not exist in namespace "microsoft". so what to do?Pls replay urgently.

Comment: I have solved the problem. actually the problem is with the PRISM 4.1 v which I downloaded because I have silverlight runtime 5. So I uninstall it and reinstall PRISM 4v and now the project is working F9. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. actually the problem is with the PRISM 4.1 v which I downloaded because I have silverlight runtime 5. So I uninstall it and reinstall PRISM 4v and now the project is working F9. :)